# Mongodb nodejs mapreduce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with following data

```
{
    id:1,
    uid:'a1',
    cat:'main',
    subject:'Hello',
},
{
    id:2,
    uid:'a1',
    cat:'a'
},
{
    id:3,
    uid:'a1',
    cat:'b'
},
```

in above collection I want to search for `{ cat:'main' }` and want to get records in below structure

```
[{
id:1,
uid:'a1',
category:'main',
subject:'Hello',
},
{
id:2,
uid:'a1',
category:'a',
subject:'Hello'
},
{
id:3,
uid:'a1',
category:'b',
subject:'Hello'
}]
```

so I am trying to search in a collection where `subject` is only present for category `main` and then I have to get other records which have same `uid` as the category `main`.

is this possible in using mapReduce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, using the aggregation pipeline. Map-reduce functions are not required.

The first approach is based on an assumption that the documents with category `main` will always be inserted before other documents for the same `uid` and will always have a `id` lesser than other documents having the same `uid`. If this point is taken care during document insertion, we can sort based on the `id` field and moreover index it.

- `Sort` based on the index field.
- `Group` by the `uid` field. So the first record for each group will be
  the `main` category record.
- `Match` only those groups which have a `main` category record.
- `Unwind` all the records in each group and apply the subject of the
  first record to all the records in each group.

The Code:

```
collection.aggregate([
{$sort:{"id":1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$uid",
         "cat":{$first:"$cat"},
         "subject":{$first:"$subject"},
         "record":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$match:{"cat":"main"}},
{$unwind:"$record"},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "id":"$record.id",
           "uid":"$_id",
           "cat":"$record.cat",
           "subject":"$subject"}}
],function(err,resp){
  console.log(resp);
 })
```

The second approach is a brute implementation of the plain example you provided, which may turn to be a lesser performer.

It requires an extra projection operator, to identify the `main` category record for each group. We sort based on this projected field. Remaining logic is same.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "id":1,"uid":1,"cat":1,"subject":1,
           "isMainRecord":{$cond:[{$eq:["$cat","main"]},0,1]}}},
{$sort:{"isMainRecord":1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$uid",
         "cat":{$first:"$cat"},"subject":{$first:"$subject"},
         "record":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$match:{"cat":"main"}},
{$unwind:"$record"},
{$project:{"_id":0,"id":"$record.id",
           "uid":"$_id","cat":"$record.cat","subject":"$subject"}}
],{allowDiskUse:true},function(err,resp){
 console.log(resp);
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I was able to build the query by following your first example but with test record of 1 million when I do search with more attributes like date range in match with limit 25 the result take almost 4-5 sec, I think it's because first all the records are sorted and then group is applied to all 1 mill records? am I correct ? is there anyway to optimize this?

Comment: Yes. You can index the id field in ascending order and remove the first sort operation.